# Post Parameter in PHPDoc

Tags: post, methods, phpdoc

i need help with this, when I´m writing PHPDoc i don´t know how i can specific post variables for a method. in this code:

```
 /**
 * Show Quarter Base Hour
 * GET: Show select Menu | POST: Get Quarter Base Hour View
 *
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function manageQuarterBaseHourAction()
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new QuarterBaseHour(), null, array('attr' => $this->container->get('formdata')->getSearchAll()));

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $year = $data['year'];
            $universe = $data['iduniverso'];
            $ficticious = $data['ficticious'];
            $quarter = $data['quarter'];
...
```

wich best way to specific that methods accepts get/post request and how can i specific post parameters, cause if i write @param is only for get params and validator turns me on error. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't actually pass arguments directly to that `manageQuarterBaseHourAction()` method, the @param tag is indeed not what you want.

It sounds like you are wanting to reader to be aware that your method will internally look at things in the $_POST superglobal.  However, in your example code, it also looks like you've separately encompassed any touching of the superglobals into proper methods rather than touching them directly in this method.

Given that aspect, I would only perhaps mention specific $_POST keys in the text description.  The only point of doing anything beyond that would be if it could provide hyperlinks to other code elements in the docs, and of course there are no docs for $_POST.  If perhaps your other methods that manage $_POST for this class might be handy to jump directly to from this method's doc, use @see tags to point to each one.  That way, if your reader thinks (s)he needs to look at the other methods while reading about this one, it's a quick click on that @see line to jump there.